# Automatically install an apk from sd card to device after every reboot of device

Tags: android

hi i am working to create an application that could'nt be deleted or uninstalled even after hard reset or formatting the device but that is failed in such rooting process ,
Now i want a code to install an app automatically from sd card after a hard reset or reboot of an android device ,
The application is to find a lost mobile so that even the lost device is resetted or formatted
my app helps a user to find his mobile
Thank you..

Comment: Installing a start-up script, or embedding the app as a system app, both require root access. Sd Card is not reliable for such storage. System partition is protected, unless a firmware flash,and Data and Cache are protected unless, factory format.

Answer (score 3):

> i am working to create an application that could'nt be deleted or uninstalled even after hard reset or formatting the device but that is failed in such rooting process

Build your own ROM mod that has your app pre-installed.

> Now i want a code to install an app automatically from sd card after a hard reset or reboot of an android device

That is not possible, fortunately, for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, There are 2 kinds of android app: System app and User app. If you want to prevent uninstalling from your app, it must be an system app.

If you are developing app for rooted phone (and your phone is rooted also), try to copy *.apk to /system/app then restart your phone.

Hope this helps.